# BlockInput in a Thread not working

Tags: c#

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);
```

If i run block input in the main thread then it executes without problems. 
If i put it in a thread and then execute it, then it returns true but doesnt block the input. 
Whats more interesting is, that if i debug the code from the inside of the thread (not from the begining) is also works.

Any idea why? shouldnt every thread have the priviledges of the main thread. Im running it under administrative priviledges by the way.

Comment: Did you check what `GetLastError` returns?

Comment: The message queue, what is getting blocked by BlockInput, is a thread-specific data structure.

Comment: Brian, there is no error, it runs smoothly.

Comment: Hans, what do you mean by that? how can i find a workaround? there must be a way to run BlockInput into a separate thread!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add manifest file to your project and make run your app eith administrator privileges. Copy this line inside manifest file.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Then try to run again, your BlockInput must run correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ BlockInput(true); });
```